# How would I remove Elmah modules from web.config using XML-Document-Transform?

Tags: visual-studio, xpath, xslt, xdt-transform, xml-document-transform

In other words, in the following web.config xml, I want to remove all  elements with a type attribute that starts with 'Elmah.'

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
```

I have tried several combinations and structures of the basic transform, with various errors,

```
<add xdt:Locator="XPath([starts-with(@type,'Elmah.')" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
```

before giving up and just removing the whole httpModules element, because no XPath is needed for that.

Answer (score 4):

The XPath Locator expects a fully qualified XPath location, so your transform is not currently matching any elements. If you use the Condition Locator (which expects a relative XPath) instead, it should match:

```
<add xdt:Locator="Condition(starts-with(@type,'Elmah.')" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll"/>
```

Note also that the xdt:Transform Remove will only operate on the first matched element, so you need to use RemoveAll to achieve what you want.

The [summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) on msdn covers this quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing each module individually?

```
<add name="ErrorLog" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
<add name="ErrorMail" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
<add name="ErrorFilter" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, theoretically not always knowing specifically which ones I need to remove.